# Need to show second shift data by selecting the starting day?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Second shift creates inventory and it is timestamped at that time. 
The issue is when it comes to reporting if I choose second shift for 1/10/2019 I wont get any of the inventory created after midnight, because the date changed.

For example: 2nd shift on the 9th produced two items. one before midnight and one after midnight. I run a report asking what second shift produced on the 9th, but it only returns pallet one and not pallet two, because pallet two technically was created on the 10th.

I can't just select second shift on the 9th and 10th, because then I'll get the last half of the 9th's second shift production, and the first half of the 10th second shift production. I'd also prefer not to make my report viewers enter a time in addition to the date.

I need one of two things...
1. a way to input this data in a way that I can get the data i need.
2. a way to output this data in a way that i can get the data I need. (this one preferably)

The data is in SQL, and I am creating this report in SSRS.
I have tried entering date and time, but still not getting desired result...

Comment: So to be clear, is the date column in your inventory table a date or a datetime data type?

Comment: @tonyd it is datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to have your Shift number in your data and it's timestamped, you can use a CASE statement to adjust the datetime based on the shift.

```
SELECT SHIFT, PRODUCTION_DATE, 
    CASE SHIFT WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -8, PRODUCTION_DATE) ELSE PRODUCTION_DATE END AS PRODUCTION_DATE_ADJUSTED
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This didn't work for me I think I did it wrong?
I added this code to the end of my selects and before my FROM

CASE ProductionReportTest.ShiftCode
WHEN 2
THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -8, ProductionReportTest.DateCreated)
ELSE ProductionReportTest.DateCreated
END AS ShiftDateCreated

Comment: Are you filtering based on the new ShiftDateCreated column? If you're filtering in the query, you'd need to use it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This is my where clause, when I try to use it I get a popup to define Query Parameters..
    WHERE((( CAST(CAST(ShiftDateCreated as date)as datetime) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND ProductionReportTest.ProducingMill = @Location) AND
ProductionReportTest.ShiftCode = @Shift)

Comment: You'd need to use the CASE statement in your WHERE clause - just paste it where the ShiftDateCreated is now, inside the `CAST( <<HERE>> as DATE)`. `WHERE((( CAST(CAST(CASE SHIFT WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -8, PRODUCTION_DATE) ELSE PRODUCTION_DATE END as date)as datetime) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) `.

Comment: That worked. I needed to have that CASE statement in the where and in the select so I can see those values as well. Thank you!